# move_uploaded_file() can't move a file cause of my permission?

Tags: php

I have a problem with PHP.

Basically, I have a script that take a file from a form, and I want to upload it on the server.

What i do is :

```
function uploadXLS($file){
$target_dir = "../uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $file["name"];

if(checkFile($file) == False) return null;
echo "checked";

$result = move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"], $target_file);
echo "move";
if($result != 1)return null;
echo "done<br>"; 
}
```

This works perfectly in localhost with Wamp, but on the server that I use (which is not mine) I the `move_uploaded_file` don't work.

I don't think there is a password or something like that, it should be an "open" server. What can I do to try to fix this problem?

Comment: Check and see if the folder has proper permissions to write to. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Has this been even read ^ *doubt it*.

Comment: i read it don't worry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the user permission on linux, you can change the permission for the file by execution this command:

```
chmod 755 your_file.jpg
```

Or for the hole folder:

```
chmod 755 -R folder/
```

Comment: So i have to ask the guys that give me the server to do that? thx :)

Comment: Yes or you can learn how to do it by yourself: http://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4094/

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark the question as resolved.

Comment: This is a very poor answer to be accepted. Firstly, it recommends setting execute permissions on a non-executable file, and completely ignores the fact that the web server is unlikely to be running as the same user as the questioner. It also ignores any possible issues that could result from something like AppArmor running on the server.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I invite you to edit the answer to improve it.

Comment: I cannot edit this answer in such a way as to make it useful. There is/was not enough information in the question for any proper answer to be constructed.